# latexindent: strange tabbing with nested braces

Tags: latexindent

I have the following code snippet, and meant to be formatted as such:

```latex
\setmainfont[
    UprightFeatures={
        SizeFeatures={
            {Size={-8.4},Font=MinionPro-Capt},
            {Size={8.4-13},Font=MinionPro-Regular},
            {Size={13-19.9},Font=MinionPro-Subh},
            {Size={19.9-},Font=MinionPro-Disp}
        },
        {RawFeature = {protrusion = mnr}},
    },
    BoldFeatures={
        SizeFeatures={
            {Size={-8.4},Font=MinionPro-BoldCapt},
            {Size={8.4-13},Font=MinionPro-Bold},
            {Size={13-19.9},Font=MinionPro-BoldSubh},
            {Size={19.9-},Font=MinionPro-BoldDisp}
        },
        {RawFeature = {protrusion=mnrb}},
    },
    ItalicFeatures={
        SizeFeatures={
            {Size={-8.4},Font=MinionPro-ItCapt},
            {Size={8.4-13},Font=MinionPro-It},
            {Size={13-19.9},Font=MinionPro-ItSubh},
            {Size={19.9-},Font=MinionPro-ItDisp}
        },
        {RawFeature = {protrusion=mni}},
    },
    BoldItalicFeatures={
        SizeFeatures={
            {Size={-8.4},Font=MinionPro-BoldItCapt},
            {Size={8.4-13},Font=MinionPro-BoldIt},
            {Size={13-19.9},Font=MinionPro-BoldItSubh},
            {Size={19.9-},Font=MinionPro-BoldItDisp}
        },
        {RawFeature = {protrusion=mnib}}
    },
    RawFeature={expansion=default},
]{Minion Pro}
```

However, applying `latexindent` to a `.tex` file containing the above code results in the mess below:

```latex
\setmainfont[
            UprightFeatures={
                SizeFeatures={
                    {Size={-8.4},Font=MinionPro-Capt},
                {Size={8.4-13},Font=MinionPro-Regular},
            {Size={13-19.9},Font=MinionPro-Subh},
            {Size={19.9-},Font=MinionPro-Disp}
            },
            {RawFeature = {protrusion = mnr}},
            },
            BoldFeatures={
                SizeFeatures={
                    {Size={-8.4},Font=MinionPro-BoldCapt},
                {Size={8.4-13},Font=MinionPro-Bold},
            {Size={13-19.9},Font=MinionPro-BoldSubh},
            {Size={19.9-},Font=MinionPro-BoldDisp}
            },
            {RawFeature = {protrusion=mnrb}},
            },
            ItalicFeatures={
                SizeFeatures={
                    {Size={-8.4},Font=MinionPro-ItCapt},
                {Size={8.4-13},Font=MinionPro-It},
            {Size={13-19.9},Font=MinionPro-ItSubh},
            {Size={19.9-},Font=MinionPro-ItDisp}
            },
            {RawFeature = {protrusion=mni}},
            },
            BoldItalicFeatures={
                SizeFeatures={
                    {Size={-8.4},Font=MinionPro-BoldItCapt},
                {Size={8.4-13},Font=MinionPro-BoldIt},
            {Size={13-19.9},Font=MinionPro-BoldItSubh},
            {Size={19.9-},Font=MinionPro-BoldItDisp}
            },
            {RawFeature = {protrusion=mnib}}
            },
            RawFeature= {expansion=default},
        ]{Minion Pro}
```

What can I do?

Comment: Apart from asking the question here (which is a good thing to do) you can also write an issue on the Latexindent [Github page](https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl/issues). Usually Chris Hughes (which is also [active here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/6621/cmhughes)) is quite responsive. However, it would help if you can reduce your code to a more minimal version that shows the issue, probably 5-10 lines of font features should be sufficient to illustrate the problem.

Comment: I'll take a look at this later today, hopefully :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### update

As of [V3.9.1](https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl/releases/tag/V3.9.1) the script gives the output given below by default, and there is no need to use any configuration (`SRSR333.yaml`), so you can simply run

```
latexindent.pl myfile.tex
```

and the output will be as below.

### original answer

The default settings allow the `keyEqualsValuesBracesBrackets` to have `{` within their names, which causes problems for your example.

We can use the `fineTuning` field in the following file:

### SRSR333.yaml

```
defaultIndent: ' '
fineTuning:
    keyEqualsValuesBracesBrackets:
      name: '[a-zA-Z@\*0-9_\/.\h:\#-]+?'
```

and run

```
latexindent.pl -l SRSR333.yaml myfile.tex
```

gives the output

```
\setmainfont[
 UprightFeatures={
   SizeFeatures={
     {Size={-8.4},Font=MinionPro-Capt},
     {Size={8.4-13},Font=MinionPro-Regular},
     {Size={13-19.9},Font=MinionPro-Subh},
     {Size={19.9-},Font=MinionPro-Disp}
    },
   {RawFeature = {protrusion = mnr}},
  },
 BoldFeatures={
   SizeFeatures={
     {Size={-8.4},Font=MinionPro-BoldCapt},
     {Size={8.4-13},Font=MinionPro-Bold},
     {Size={13-19.9},Font=MinionPro-BoldSubh},
     {Size={19.9-},Font=MinionPro-BoldDisp}
    },
   {RawFeature = {protrusion=mnrb}},
  },
 ItalicFeatures={
   SizeFeatures={
     {Size={-8.4},Font=MinionPro-ItCapt},
     {Size={8.4-13},Font=MinionPro-It},
     {Size={13-19.9},Font=MinionPro-ItSubh},
     {Size={19.9-},Font=MinionPro-ItDisp}
    },
   {RawFeature = {protrusion=mni}},
  },
 BoldItalicFeatures={
   SizeFeatures={
     {Size={-8.4},Font=MinionPro-BoldItCapt},
     {Size={8.4-13},Font=MinionPro-BoldIt},
     {Size={13-19.9},Font=MinionPro-BoldItSubh},
     {Size={19.9-},Font=MinionPro-BoldItDisp}
    },
   {RawFeature = {protrusion=mnib}}
  },
 RawFeature={expansion=default},
]{Minion Pro}
```

Comment: Works perfectly!

Comment: @SRSR333 great :) I've updated the script, and as of V3.9.1, the output is given by default, no need for configuration. It should be on ctan very soon, and you'll be able to get it by [updating your distribution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution) :)